# Should I include a statement on cover letter about people in my life with experience in the field?

Tags: new-job, cover-letter

I am applying to a data science position with a company in the education sphere. The position is technical only and I meet the basic requirements and most of the preferred requirements. It does not require experience in education, it does involve using data to measure teacher's performance.

My wife has worked in education her entire professional career and is the VP for Continuing Ed on our state's speech-language association, I also have a son just now entering 1st grade who has been diagnosed with ADHD, so while I do not have experience in the field I have a lot of exposure to the ins and outs.

Is it a good idea to include any of this in a cover letter? Or maybe parts? (like having a grade school child without mentioning learning disabilities)

Comment: @Carcosa But there is something to be said for what the OP has learned from his wife over the years. I would say that the OP certainly knows more about education than someone with identical work experience who is not married to an educator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add anything in the cover letter that will highlight some aspect of you or your experience that will show that you should be offered the job.

It is often used to highlight some experience you have, but it can also be used show a passion you have for the industry, company, or project. While it doesn't make sense to say hire me because my spouse does X; it might be useful to explain why you are passionate about education. It may show that your passion will make you more likely to be dedicated to the project, and more likely to stay for a long period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Since the role doesn't require knowledge of education, then you don't need to go out of your way to include this.

You can of course include your experience of education into your cover letter as a way of increasing your awareness of context in your proposed role and pitch this as such.